# My attempt at computing transformation of Christoffel symbols under frame transformation

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, solution-verification

Let $\triangledown$ be a connection on $M$. Suppose we are given two local frames $\{E_i\}$ and $\{\tilde{E}_i\}$ on an open subset $U \subset M$, related by $\tilde{E}_i=A_i^jE_j$ for some matrix of functions $(A_i^j)$. Let $\Gamma_{i,j}^k$ and $\tilde{\Gamma}_{i,j}^k$ denote the Christoffel symbols of $\triangledown$ with respect to these two frames. Compute the law expressing $\Gamma_{i,j}^k$ in terms of $\tilde{\Gamma}_{i,j}^k$ and $A_i^j$.

---

My attempt: I just looked for some relationship through evaluating the connection on basis elements on each frame.

$\Sigma_{k=1}^n\tilde{\Gamma}_{i,j}^k=\triangledown_{\tilde{E}_i}\tilde{E}_j=\triangledown_{A_i^zE_z}A_j^wE_w$ where we are using Einstein summation notation.

Carrying on, we have:

$\triangledown_{A_i^zE_z}A_j^wE_w=A_i^z\triangledown_{E_z}A_j^wE_w=A_i^z(E_zA_j^w)E_w+A_j^w\triangledown_{E_z}E_w=\tilde{E_i}\tilde{E_j}+A_j^w\triangledown_{E_z}E_w=\tilde{E_i}\tilde{E_j}+A_j^w(\Sigma_{k=1}^n\Gamma_{z,w}^k)$

Thus, by relabeling, we have:

$\Sigma_{k=1}^n\tilde{\Gamma}_{i,j}^k=\tilde{E_i}\tilde{E_j}+A_j^w(\Sigma_{k=1}^n\Gamma_{z,w}^k)$

This isn't right.. I must have messed up my summations somewhere.. Does anybody see where my error is?

Also, this probably a very inefficient method anyway, as I'm not relating one Christoffel symbol to another, but rather a summatino of them in one frame to a summation in the other frame.

Help appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Just to emphasize: The most serious error occurred in the first equation. $\nabla_{\tilde E_i}\tilde E_j$ has to be a linear combination of $\tilde E_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you don't use the product rule correctly, and also what you claim to be computing isn't exactly what you actually compute.

Using the definition of the Christoffel symbols and the relation between the frames, we have

$$ \nabla_{\tilde{E}_i} \tilde{E}_j = \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^k \tilde{E}_k = \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^k A_k^l E_l  $$

(which is not what you wrote in the question body).

On the other hand, using the relation between the frames and the product rule, we have

$$ \nabla_{\tilde{E}_i} \tilde{E}_j = \nabla_{A^z_i E_z} \left( A^w_j E_w \right) = A_i^z \left( \nabla_{E_z} \left( A^w_j E_w \right) \right) = A_i^z \left( \left( E_z A^w_j \right)E_w + A^w_j \nabla_{E_z} E_w \right) \\
=  A_i^z \left( \left( E_z A^w_j \right)E_w + A^w_j \Gamma_{zw}^k E_k\right).  $$

Relabeling the indices and cleaning up, we have

$$ \nabla_{\tilde{E}_i} \tilde{E}_j = \left( A_i^z \left( E_z A^l_j \right) +  A_i^z A^w_j \Gamma^l_{zw} \right) E_l. $$

Comparing both expressions, we get

$$ \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^k A_k^l = \left( A_i^z \left( E_z A^l_j \right) +  A_i^z A^w_j \Gamma^l_{zw} \right). $$

Multiplying both sides by $\left( A^{-1} \right)^r_l$ the left side becomes

$$ \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^k A_k^l \left( A^{-1} \right)^r_l = \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^k \delta_k^r = \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^r $$

while the right hand side is

$$ \left( A_i^z \left( E_z A^l_j \right) +  A_i^z A^w_j \Gamma^l_{zw} \right)\left( A^{-1} \right)^r_l$$

and so you get

$$ \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^r = \left( A_i^z \left( E_z A^l_j \right) +  A_i^z A^w_j \Gamma^l_{zw} \right)\left( A^{-1} \right)^r_l. $$

You can clean up the right hand side a little but this already gives you the transformation rule between the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: Thanks! How did you know to make the bottom index for the inverse matrix of $A$ match the top index for $A$? Everything worked out nicely, but would it have been wrong to make the top index of the inverse matrix match the bottom index of the normal matrix? Would you just have to relabel the kronecker before you match it with the Christoffel??? This stuff is tricky!!

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa: The thing that helps you is the summation convention. In the expression $\tilde{\Gamma}^k_{ij} A^l_k$ you have three "free" indices $i,j,l$ and one index over which you sum $k$. If you would have multiplied everything by $(A^{-1})^k_r$ the index $k$ would appear three times and not two and you couldn't cancel them. The whole "summation over repeated indices when one is up and one is down" convention also tells you where you should place the indices on $A^{-1}$ to get everything right.